# How to update a secondary tile in the OnNavigatedFrom event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I have implemented live tiles in my application, whereby a user may pin a secondary tile to the start screen. The issue I am having is how to update the BackgroundImage of the secondary tile when the user selects a new image in the application. As far as I can tell, the best way to update the BackgroundImage so the user always sees the new image he or she has chosen, is to update the secondary tile in the OnNavigatedFrom event on my MainPage. I am not sure how to udpate a secondary tile though that is not created in a click event.

To add a little bit more detail, my application has a hubtile, and I have created a ContextMenu with a 'pin to start' option and a 'change image' option. The 'change image' option loads the PhotoChooserTask and allows the user to pick an image from there and then saves that image in isolated storage and applies it to the hubtile. When the user clicks 'pin to start', a secondary tile is created which has the same image as its respective hubtile. So far this works, but when I change the image in the application's hubtile, I do not know how to automatically update the respective secondary tile's image on the start screen. Every method I have researched online shows how to update a tile instance in the same click event as where the tile is created (perhaps in a button click event saying 'create tile'), but how would I get an instance of this tile to update in another method or event handler, such as the OnNavigatedFrom event?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the secondary tile and add it like a new one from your onnavigatedfrom code